# Write a user accepted input into text file in ios development

Tags: ios, file-io

I am new to ios development.I am getting a difficulty in writing a user accepted input into text file. Rightnow I am accepting user's input into 'alert'.But now I want user's input to be directly written in the text file.Is it possible? How can I implement this?

Comment: alert means textfield in uialertview? and you want to write the text to a text file?

Comment: @Rashad: Yes I want to write text in the text file.But on the top of that is it possible that,the text which I am going to write into that text file will be entered by user? Just asking because I do not have much knowledge about ios development

Comment: @user3886591 Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Once I found this somewhere in SO, it worked for me:

```
-(void) writeToTextFile{
        //documents directory:
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
            (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt", 
                                                      documentsDirectory];
        //create content - four lines of text
        NSString *content = @"One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive";
        //save content to the documents directory
        [content writeToFile:fileName 
                         atomically:NO 
                               encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
                                      error:nil];

}

-(void) displayContent{
        //documents directory:
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                        (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt", 
                                                      documentsDirectory];
        NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName
                                                      usedEncoding:nil
                                                             error:nil];

}
```

**EDIT:**

`UIAlertView` has a delegate method called `clickedButtonAtIndex`. implement this delegate in your controller. Then from there you can get the text. Like:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Save"]){
        NSString *yourText = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
    }
    else if ([title isEqualToString:@"NO"]){

    }
}
```

Remember to add AlertView delegate to self.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: :It works perfectly fine for me :) thanks! What I wanted to ask  is,I am accepting inputs from the user in alert,now I want that inputs   to get write into the text file.Any idea how we can do this??